# I'm manipulating an array of objects in order to have unique values with lodash using the functions _.reject and _.uniqBy

Tags: javascript, lodash

The problem is that the function returns the same array unchanged

```
var result2 = _.reject(self.arraytot2, ({ Ecuid }) =>                 

_.uniqBy(self.arraytot2, {Ecuid})) ;

//the array is the following

self.arraytot2 = [{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_.uniqBy()` directly, and pass the unique key:

```js
const arraytot2 = [{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":11},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19},{"Ecuid":19}];

const result = _.uniqBy(arraytot2, 'Ecuid');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```